# How to update user claims stored in authentication cookie in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, cookie-authentication

I have a Razor Pages app developed using .NET Core 6. The app works as a client and connects to an API. The API has JWT Access Token/Refresh Token authentication. The login endpoint of the API returns access token and refresh token.Using [cookie authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0) I store the tokens as claim in authentication cookie.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Login.Email),
            new Claim("Token", loginResponse.Token),
            new Claim("RefreshToken", loginResponse.RefreshToken)
        };
```

I then get the tokens using extension methods

```
public static class CommonExtensions
{
    public static string? GetToken(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "Token").Value.ToString();
    }

    public static string? GetRefreshToken(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "RefreshToken").Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

When my access token expires I refresh it, remove existing claims and add new ones with the updated token.

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("Token"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Token", response.Token));

identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("RefreshToken"));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("RefreshToken", response.RefreshToken));
```

However the subsequent requests keep using the expired token. What is the way to update the claims correctly?

Comment: When you update Claims in ClaimsIdentity, You need to save change and update the token in cookie. Actually , I didn't find any effective method except to SignIn again.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `CookieAuthenticationEvents`, and you can update the Principal when you validate it.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents
    : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    ...

    public override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        ...

        if (needToUpdateCookie)
        {
            var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("Token"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Token", response.Token));

            identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst("RefreshToken"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("RefreshToken", response.RefreshToken));

            context.ShouldRenew = true;
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

In your bootstrap...

```cs
// Off course you can inject the dependencies to CostomCookieAuthenticationEvents...
builder.Services.AddScope<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        ...

        options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);

        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save your changes you would need to call `SignInAsync` according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, User);
```

If it does not work, maybe you need to call `SignOutAsync` first.

Comment: Signing in again works but it invalids the remaining requests for the same page and I have to refresh the page manually. Is there a way to reload the same page after signing in again, Return Page(); doesn't seem to be working.